# Parsing part of an input tag with lxml and Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml

I have an input-tag looking like this:

```
<input name="sheet" value="5B" tabindex="994" data-enpassid="__11" type="submit">
```

No I want to get only the content given to the value-attribute (5B in this case). Is this possibe using lxml and if so, how?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the actual `value` of your input element, e.g., the expected output for your case is `5B`?

Comment: Reading my question again, I noticed that this isn't even a span-tag but an input-tag. No idea how this happened, but sorry if it led to confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I've created two expressions using css selector and xpath. They both will give you `5B` as result:

```
html='''
<input name="sheet" value="5B" tabindex="994" data-enpassid="__11" type="submit">
'''
from lxml.html import fromstring

root = fromstring(html)
item = root.cssselect("input")[0].attrib['value']
item1 = root.xpath("//input/@value")[0]
print(item, item1)
```

Result:

```
5B, 5B
```